# how do I use my import package's struct as a type in go

Tags: go

I'm working in a project and using "database/sql" package in go. And I want to use struct "DB" that declare in package "database/sql" as an argument to my func, so I can use the return value by sql.Open() and as my func's argument. Was it possible? Codes are below:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL"
)

func main() {
    var table string = "tablename"

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")

    // read data from database
    read(db, table)
}

func read(db *DB, table string) {
    // read
}
```

This code throws a "undefined: DB" error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must use a qualifier for imported entities - the package name from where the 'name' comes from:

```
func read(db *sql.DB, table string)
```

Comment: Ok, so I am having issues.  So whenever I have it return though, the type switches from *sql.DB to *DB.  Whenever I try to perform a test, it complains that *sql.DB != *DB, so therefore they can't use the mockDB that I am creating to input into the parameter that takes *sql.DB.