# Update global scope variable value

Tags: go

I have json file which has thousand of records as key value pair of which I read those by unmarshalling it as interface.

```
var devices map[string]interface{} //globalscope in app
jsonFast:= jsoniter.ConfigFastest
_, b, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
dir := filepath.Dir(b)

jsonFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(dir + "/devices.json")
_ = jsonFast.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &devices)
```

This is accessed by several goroutine over the course of the app under highload.

Now As this file gets updated every 5 minute, so without restarting the app I want to invalidate this map interface `devices` to have a fresh data loaded from file.

In node.js I used to use `delete require.cache[require.resolve("filename")]` but not sure how this can be done in go.

I have tried to use mutex lock in SetInterval func(A port of node version) I used from [here](https://www.loxodrome.io/post/set-timeout-interval-go/) which reads the file after every 5 minute but I get this error:

`goroutine 871895 [IO wait]:` which seems to means that goroutine are awaiting unlock to read from the global variable.

Code:

```
    var m sync.Mutex
    //this function execute every 5 minute to read file and reassign to map interface.
    _ = setInterval(func() {

        jsonFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(dir + "/devices.json")
        m.Lock() // used this mutex as the step may cause race condition.
        _ = jsonFast.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &devices)
        m.Unlock()

    }, 5* 60 * 1000, false)

    //this initializes at the start after which the set interval execute every 5 minute to get updated data.
    jsonFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(dir + "/devices.json")
    _ = jsonFast.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &devices)
```

What should be my approach to achieve this?Or Is there any way to read/update from the file instead of using map interface in order to avoid race condition and IO lock?

Comment: `goroutine 871895 [IO wait]` is not the error, that's the status of the goroutine. The error should be at the beginning of the dump. Pls include the actual error.

Comment: One way of ensuring map access is slightly safer is wrapping the entire map in a `sync.RWMutex`, but that would require locking the entire map before reading/writing. If your JSON has a known structure, you should most likely unmarshal it into a struct, and then wrap each part of the struct in a mutex.

Comment: @JohnOss, the code is currently locking the map already. What would such a fine-grained approach accomplish when replacing the whole struct? The problem with the current code is that unless all reads are done with the same mutex, it is racy. But let's see that error first.

Comment: Using jsoniter might be sensible but why using it after ioutil.ReadFile? Premature optimisation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that the issue relates to the fact that you still have goroutines *reading* from the map while you are trying to overwrite it with new data.  I would recommend you use a `sync.RWMutex` to protect it, and do it like this:

```
type GlobalState struct {
    data map[string]interface{}
    sync.RWMutex
}

func (gs *GlobalState) Get(key string) interface{} {
    gs.RLock()
    defer gs.RUnlock()
    return gs.data[key]
}

func (gs *GlobalState) Refresh() {
    jsonFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(dir + "/devices.json")
    gs.Lock()
    defer gs.Unlock()
    _ = jsonFast.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &gs.data)
}

var devices GlobalState

func main() {
    t := time.NewTicker(5 * 60 * time.Second)
    for ; true; <-t.C {
         devices.Refresh()
    }
}
```

Then you have safe reads (but need to do `devices.Get(key)` instead of `devices[key]`), *and* safe writes.  Also, at the end it's cleaned up a bit so you don't have to repeat your code to make the timer run immediately.

Comment: I will try this out, I hope this will not lock any goroutine and will efficient on memory and CPU?

Comment: App doesn't listen on port after I added `time.NewTicker` code before/after `log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())`, is this expected or Am I doing something wrong?Also can I put `type GlobalState ` in different package?
Needed this after doing so, didn't helped though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898400/import-struct-from-another-package-and-file-golang

Comment: You'll need to run the ticker part in a goroutine

Comment: Oh OK, so its like using ListenAndServe() multiple times which is also need to be used in goroutine if we need to listen on multiple port, Thanks. What about using `type GlobalState` from other package and use it different package in course of app?Any help there?

Comment: Yeah no reason your couldn't put it in it's own package, and just use a singleton pattern or something if that's what you mean